# HBase 1.2.1 standalone in Docker unable to connect

Tags: java, docker, connection, hbase

I want to connect to HBase running in standalone in a docker, using Java and the HBase API

I use this code to connect :

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "163.172.142.199");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX hbase-srv
```

Here is the /etc/hosts file from my docker (named hbase-srv)

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX hbase-srv
```

With this configuration, I get a connection refused error :

```
 INFO | Initiating client connection, connectString=163.172.142.199:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x6aba2b860x0, quorum=163.172.142.199:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
 INFO | Opening socket connection to server 163.172.142.199/163.172.142.199:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
 INFO | Socket connection established to 163.172.142.199/163.172.142.199:2181, initiating session
 INFO | Session establishment complete on server 163.172.142.199/163.172.142.199:2181, sessionid = 0x15602f8d8dc0002, negotiated timeout = 40000
 INFO | Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x15602f8d8dc0002
 INFO | Session: 0x15602f8d8dc0002 closed
 INFO | EventThread shut down
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:3159)
    at hbase.Benchmark.main(Benchmark.java:26)
```

However, if I remove the lines `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX hbase-srv` from both `/etc/hosts` files I get the error `unknown host : hbase-srv`

I have also checked, I can successfully *telnet* to my hbase docker on the client port.

On the docker, all the ports used by HBase are opened and binded to the same number (60000 on 60000, 2181 on 2181, etc).

I also wanted to add that all was fine when I used this configuration on localhost.

If you can't give me an answer to my problem, could you at least give me a procedure to deploy a standalone hbase on a docker.

UPDATE : Here is my Docker file

```
FROM java:openjdk-8

ADD hbase-1.2.1 /hbase-1.2.1

WORKDIR /hbase-1.2.1
# ZooKeeper
EXPOSE 2181

# HMaster
EXPOSE 60000

# HMaster Web
EXPOSE 60010

# RegionServer
EXPOSE 60020

# RegionServer Web
EXPOSE 60030

EXPOSE 16010

RUN chmod 755 /hbase-1.2.1/bin/start-hbase.sh
CMD ["/hbase-1.2.1/bin/start-hbase.sh"]
```

My HBase shell is working, I also tried to open the port using iptables for tcp and udp but still the same problem

Comment: have you exposed all the necessary ports ? maybe https://github.com/dajobe/hbase-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile this post can give you some hints.

Comment: I used the command docker -p 60000:60000 etc but I don't know if it is the same thing as EXPOSE, I will try tomorrow at work and give you the result, thanks !

Comment: I have tried with the expose but it doesn't work, I put my dockerfile in the question if you can see any information valuable inside of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your Dockerfile:

1. use `hbase master start` instead of `start-hbase.sh`
2. **regionserver is actually not running on 60020**

The 2nd problem is not so easy to solve. If run hbase standalone with version >= 1.2.0 (not sure, I'm running 1.2.0), hbase will use ephemeral port instead of the default port or the port you provide in `hbase-site.xml` which makes it very hard to provide hbase service in docker using the original version.

I add a property named `hbase.localcluster.port.ephemeral` and managed to build a standalone hbase in docker, which you can reference [here](https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase.docker).

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much ! Thanks for your time. Now my hbase is deployed on my docker, and I can request it

Comment: @sel-fish you just saved my life.

Comment: that property is not specified anywhere in the official doc, please add a source. And why starting hbase with start-hbase.sh is wrong?? It is the recommended way from the official doc

Comment: @Marc I think I already add a source about the extra parameter, https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase.docker , you can see from the Readme. As this answer is written  about 7 years ago, if the description of use 'hbase master start' is not proper now, please help to edit it, thanks for feedback anyway, have a nice day.